# Intuition for Replacement theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the intuition behind replacement theorem of vector spaces?

**Statement**

Let $V$ be vector space that is generated by set $G$ containing exactly $n$ vectors, and let $L$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$ containing exactly $m$ vectors. Then $m \leq n$ and there exists a subset H of G containing exactly $n-m$ vectors such that $L \cup H$ generates V

Thanks

Comment: Basically there exists only one vector space (up to isomorphism) over a field $K$ of dimension $n$. So any basis of size $m$ combined with a separate basis of size $n - m$ generates "an" $n$-dimensional vector space, which is actually "the" $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Just so this has an answer:

First I'm guessing you know how the proof goes, $L$ is given and to find $H$, pick vectors in the complement of the span of $L$.

The intuition behind this I suppose is that given a set $L$ of linearly independent vectors from a space $V$, you can complete this (non-uniquely) to a basis for $V$.

For example take $\Bbb R^3$, and  $L=\{(1,0,0)\}$, there's the obvious way to complete this to the standard basis, or just pick any two linearly independent vectors with a zero in the first entry like $(0,1,1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$.